# Cannot retrieve JSON data from Last.FM's API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, last.fm

I am working on a school project and have run into trouble. Namely, I am building a simple AngularJS app which shows some kind of a radio chart based on [Last.FM's data](http://www.last.fm/api/show/chart.getTopTracks).

However, when trying to access the API, I never get a response.

This is the code that I use for accessing:

```js
APIservice.getChartTracks = function () {
    return $http({
        method: 'JSONP',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json'
    });
}
```

Afterwards, when I do something like this:

```js
APIservice.getChartTracks().success(function (response) {
    $scope.tracks = response.tracks.track;
});
```

the `success()` method never gets called. If I were to change the `url` to [this one](http://ergast.com/api/f1/2013/driverStandings.json?callback=JSON_CALLBACK) (found it on some online tutorial), I get a response and everything.

How should I go about accessing Last.FM's API?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you used your web-browser's tools to inspect the HTTP request/response?  You could be getting back an error.  In Chrome you can press F12 and click on Network to find the request/response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [`$http`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http), the method to use is `GET`, not `JSONP`. Write:

```
return $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json'
    });
```

Or use the shortcut:

```
return $http.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=chart.gettoptracks&api_key=MY_API_KEY&format=json');
```

Comment: Indeed this seems to be the case, but doing so results in some random error from AngularJS. Oh, well.

Comment: I have got it to work. Thanks a lot! The problem I was having stemmed from my Firefox Nightly add-ons being overly 'obtrusive.' Aside from this, you have also directed me towards learning about different methods (I was aware of `GET` doing what it does, but really thought that I should use `JSONP` despite there being no `JSON_CALLBACK`). Again, thanks a lot.